# Symfony 2 image with relative path display

Tags: symfony, path

I don't understand, why relative path for my image url don't work.

My image located at `/web/bundles/mybundle/upload/image.jpg`

In my template:

```
<img src = "bundles/mybundle/upload/image.jpg"/>
```

Application entry point  - **app.php** is located in **/web** folder, on the same level as **bundles** folder and I suppose to see my image, when I render template.

But it seems, that image path is incorrect, because I do not see my image.

Only absolute path, with host, renders it correctly.

Can I use relative path or should proceed with absolute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use the embeded asset package system, that resolves correctly the assets relative paths:

```
<img src="{{ asset('bundles/mybundle/upload/image.jpg') }}" />
```

Note that adding a leading slah ("/") has an impact.

Comment: Could you explain more why adding a leading slash has an impact?